# White text on white background in ListFragment using Theme.Light

Tags: android, list, android-fragments

My problem is, that I get white text on a white background like in the image below. When i click on it the text gets black

[image]

This is my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/actionbar"
    style="@style/SPActionBar" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/layout_home_list_fragment"
    android:name="at.bartinger.smartphonelib.activity.fragment.ProfileListFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_home_adlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>
```

ProfileListFragment extends ListFragment and as I said the whole application uses Theme.Light (in Manifest xml)

Comment: it should be black as default

Comment: it is white on black background. as u changed background as white. u should change text color as black

Comment: as i said I'm using Theme.Light. It changes the background to white and should change the text color to black, but it doesn't. I don't modify anything manually. All handled by the theme

Answer (score 3):

Are you using this in your SimpleCursorAdapter :

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext()
```

If so, replace with

```
getActivity().getBaseContext()
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: In reading about getBaseContext(), it sounds like it should be avoided. I was able to fix this issue by using getView().getContext() instead.